# « et patati et patata » Comment utiliser cette expression ?

Tags: expressions

Quand on énumére plusieurs choses, « et ainsi de suite » ou « et j'en passe » s'emploie d'habitude pour eviter de faire une liste trop longue.

Je m'interroge sur la différence entre ces deux expressions et « et patati et patata ». Est-ce que « et patati et patata » est un équivalent à l'expression anglaise « blah-blah-blah » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« Patati, patata » (parfois « patati, patala ») est une expression familière qui ne s'emploie pas dans les mêmes contextes que « ainsi de suite » ou « et j'en passe ». On ne l'emploie pas pour éviter de faire une liste trop longue ou parce qu'on sous-entend que la suite est connue de son interlocuteur (ce qui peut être le cas avec « et ainsi de suite, ou « et j'en passe ») mais c'est péjoratif et familier pour dire que la suite est sans importance et inutile.

Le DHLF ne donne pas la même étymologie que le [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patati) mais donne une origine onomatopéique :

> .. recouvre plusieurs onomatopées tirées d'un radical expressif *patt-* qui évoque un bruit de choc, de coup, de galopade, de bavardage, etc.

L'expression est apparue au 18<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Au contraire de « [blabla](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/blabla) (bla-bla-bla) » (ou blablabla/bla-bla-bla) beaucoup plus récent,(20<sup>e</sup> siècle) « patati patata » ne s'emploie pas comme nom commun.

Comment: Je l’ai déjà entendu, surtout avec **tout**, employé  comme espèce de substantif.  («[et] tout le/ce patati [et patata]»). Est-ce que l’on doit considérer un tel usage comme aberrant/une erreur?

Comment: @PapaPoule Moi je ne l'ai jamais entendu, mais personnellement je considère que c'est l'usage qui fait la langue et c'est parler « d'erreur » dans un tel cas qui serait aberrant. Si on le dit et si c'est compris je considère que c'est correct. Les langues ne sont pas des objets figés, les gens qui les parlent les font évoluer., de nouveaux mots et de nouveaux emplois se créent tous les jours.

Comment: Le propos du _Wiktionnaire_ est surprenant ; le [_TLFi_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/patati) dans le même sens que le _DHLF_, et avec une variante avec l'impayable Proust : « Elle a toujours quelque chose à dire, que je ferme mal les portes, et patatipatali et patatatipatala. » !

Answer (score 1):

En français on utilise aussi l'expression :

> "Bla, bla, bla"

"et patati et patata" est dans un registre assez familier et est assez similaire à "Bla, bla, bla". Généralement on l'emploie pour éluder une énumération infinissable et souvent sans intérêt. Par exemple :

> Ce garçon essayait de me séduire en me disant qu'il était beau, qu'il était fort et patati et patata.

Je dirai que :

> "Bla, bla, bla"
>
> "Et patati et patata"

Sont plus familiers et ont un côté plus théâtral que :

> "et j'en passe"
>
> "et ainsi de suite"

Comment: Hi. Is it usual to omit "et des meilleures" from "et j'en passe"? Merci.

Comment: Yes it is some people say "j'en passe et des meilleures" but more often we say "et j'en passe". With my previous example we could say : "Ce garçon a essayé de me séduire en me disant qu'il était beau, qu'il était fort ... j'en passe et des meilleures" ou : "Ce garçon a essayé de me séduire en me disant qu'il était beau, qu'il était fort et j'en passe".